# Tooltip Angular ejs lineargauge

Tags: angular, ejs, syncfusion

I am working on a tooltip with ejs lineargauge, I have checked all the attributes whether in the documentation or in the internal classes, but none of the attributes is working.
I want to change the content ; text color and background color

This is the part of the HTML code:

anycomponent.component.html

```
<ejs-lineargauge #axesActivite (tooltipRender)='tooltipRender($event)' [allowMargin]="false"
[axes]='axesAct'[tooltip]="tooltip"
```

This is the part of ts file anycomponent.component.ts
After export class....

```
 tooltip: Object = {
    type: ['Range'],
    enable: true,
    position: 'Center',
    fill: '#e5bcbc',
```

None of the attributes is working only Range and enable are working, all the others are not working whether fill or position.

Answer (score -1):

When we analyzed the provided code snippet and we came to know that you are trying to render tooltip for the range but the **“rangeSettings”** property of **“tooltipSettings”** is not initialized for customization. The color of the text and the fill color of the tooltip can be changed using **“color”** property in the **“textStyle”** property of **“rangeSettings”**. The content of the tooltip can be changed via **“tooltipRender”** event using the “content” event argument.

**Code Snippet:**

**[app.component.html]**

```
<ejs-lineargauge

    (tooltipRender)="tooltipRender($event)"

    [tooltip]="tooltip">

  </ejs-lineargauge>
```

**[app.component.ts]**

```
public tooltip: Object = {
rangeSettings: {

      fill: 'skyblue',

      textStyle: {

        color: 'red',

      },

    },
};

public tooltipRender(args: ITooltipRenderEventArgs): void {

    args.content = "Pointer Range text customization";

  }
```

We have created a sample to demonstrate the same and it can be found from the below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gj5ggd-63opwd?file=app.component.html

Comment: Offsite links are strongly discouraged. You can post complete stack snippets right here.